# Down sample Audio 44100Kz to 8000Kz

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, audio-streaming

I have AudioBufferList(also created NSData) with sample rate 44100Kz and wants to down sample it to 8000Kz. So if any one have any idea about down sampling please let me know. Great Idea will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: change your samplerate..

Comment: how can i change it. please define.?

Comment: your using mediarecoder or audiorecoder functions ????

Comment: Oh dear i know but here i tags it with iOS, iPhone , Xcode

Comment: sorry .. dint saw the tags.. I dont know with IOS..

Comment: thanks.. I ll let you know if I get any ideas..

Comment: basically in iOS do't set static value like Java so need some kind of algorithm and pick some byte in some order with logic so it will downsample

Comment: Do all 12 of your questions really not have acceptable answers?

Comment: Give some Guidelines .? @Almo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using pick the every 6 byte from the byte array you making with your raw data and please try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690395/my-ios-app-using-audio-units-with-an-8000-hertz-sample-rate-returns-a-distorted)

Comment: 44.1 KHz / 6 = 7.35 KHz, which is not 8 KHz.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing. I have set it to 8000 but im getting a distorted sound. you can see my code in this question to change the sample rate:

[my iOS app using audio units with an 8000 hertz sample rate returns a distorted voice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690395/my-ios-app-using-audio-units-with-an-8000-hertz-sample-rate-returns-a-distorted)